# Store Date to UTC one-liner by PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone, utc

I understand that it is best practice to always store dates as UTC into databases but I am quite confused in this scenario I am in. Let's say I have a form where the end-user inserts a date "07-15-2016" in Eastern Timezone. Would it be necessary to store this as a UTC date or just **as-is** since it's not DateTime?

I'm currently using a one-liner in PHP to sanitize the date to a format before I insert it into the database.

```
// User input is 07-15-2016 and will be formatted to 2016-07-15 00:00:00
$userDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '07-15-2016')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Is there anything I could do to make sure nothing messes up since the user-input is EST; meanwhile, the time is 00:00:00?

Comment: you store in utc when you aren't sure what a date will be used for in the future. it's EASY to convert utc->anything, while TZ1 -> TZ2 can be more complicated. if you **KNOW** that you'll never be dealing with anything other than EST timezone values, then feel free to store those values as EST times.